# Value for parameter MessageDeduplicationId is invalid. Reason: The request includes a parameter that is not valid for this queue type

Tags: spring-boot, queue, aws-cli, amazon-sqs, localstack

I have a queue in SQS running locally via Localstack. I already configured my .env to talk to my indexer and my api. But when I run it gives me this message:

```
Value I4nCE8HRz0M for parameter MessageDeduplicationId is 
invalid. Reason: The request includes a parameter that is 
not valid for this queue type.
```

I'm a bit confused as to what it could be since Localstack is running normally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem occurs because you're trying to send message to a FIFO queue, but you've created a standard queue. Instead of running command:

```
LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.execInContainer("awslocal", "sqs", "create-queue", "--queue-name", QUEUE_NAME);
```

You should run this one:

```
LOCAL_STACK_CONTAINER.execInContainer("awslocal", "sqs", "create-queue", "--queue-name", QUEUE_NAME, "--attributes", "{\"FifoQueue\":\"true\"}");
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i also got that error. and i was because the message sent to the normal queue had the deduplicationId header. normal queue does not like that header